# How to get handle of a checkbox on TAB control. Win32 VC++

Tags: c#, winapi, visual-c++

I have created a TAB control with 3 tabs in it. In the third tab, there is a checkbox and I want to get handle of this checkbox at run time from other application. From outside application I am getting the handle of TAB control.  But how to get handle of checkbox on the third tab of this TAB control.

Comment: Do you mean [`TabControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx)? In winforms getting handle is as simple as `Control.Handle`. What do you mean when say *outside application*? Do you have visual c++ window and trying to pass handle of checkbox to winform/console/wpf c# application or vise-versa?

Comment: Yes the checkbox is on a TabControl. This tab control is in a vc++ application. And from a C# application I want to get handle of the checkbox. I am able to get handle of TabControl, but I cannot get handle of checkbox.

Comment: If you know the control ID of the checkbox (Spy++) and the tab control IS its parent then you can call GetDlgItem(parent, ctrlID) or the C# equiv.

Answer (score 0):

[EnumChildWindows?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There could be some complications if the application is written in a non-Win32 framework such as WPF because they don't always use Win32 child controls. In that case [Windows Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the only cross-framework API I know of (YMMV).

If you're using Visual Studio (not Express) and you're not familiar with Spy++ then fire that up and give it a go -- it's interesting if nothing else, it let's you explore the rather surprising number of windows that exist.